# Failing to pass Integer via bundle, from Activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, bundle

In my activity, I have this code

```
private void loadFragment(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        RecyclerViewFragment fragment = new RecyclerViewFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        User currentUser = new UserDAO(getApplicationContext()).findAll().
                get( currentUserId() );
        bundle.putSerializable("userNotes", currentUser.getNotes());
        bundle.putInt("userId", currentUser.getId());

        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        transaction.replace(R.id.notesFragment, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

and this in my recyclerview fragment:

```
private void initDataset() {
    ArrayList<Note> userNotes = (ArrayList<Note>) getArguments().getSerializable("userNotes");
    String test = String.valueOf(getArguments().getInt("userId", 999));


    mDataset = new String[userNotes.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < userNotes.size(); i++) {
        mDataset[i] =
                  "####################################" +
                "\n# Name: " + userNotes.get(i).getName() + " " + test +
                "\n# Date: " + userNotes.get(i).getDate()+
                "\n####################################";
    }
}
```

When I use this, I have the app correctly printing a list with name and date of Note objects.
However, 'test' variable always prints as the default value (999) because its null.

Initially, I thought this was happening because while User.getNotes returns the ArrayList correctly, User.getId was simply null.
The thing is, also in my activity, I have this block of code

```
private void changeTextView() {
    User currentUser = new UserDAO(getApplicationContext()).findAll().
            get( currentUserId() );

    tvDesc.setText("Current user is: "+currentUser.getName() + " ID: "+currentUser.getId());
}
```

It correctly gets the user name, and the id, and changes a textview.

Why is this happening?

Why is it that I can get the textView to update correctly in activity using `currentUser.getId()`, but when I pass `bundle.putInt("userId", currentUser.getId());` I get null/default value. While `bundle.putSerializable("userNotes", currentUser.getNotes());` just works

Comment: `However, 'test' variable` ? We would name that `userId`. Try with putString().

Comment: I did try with putString, and test variable receiving with only ".getArguments().getString" instead of valueOf, but the result is the same